# How can I Get ErrorProvider's Tooltip?

Tags: .net, vb.net, tooltip, errorprovider

I need some help to get the `ErrorProvider`'s tooltip from 3rd party app. Is there any sample to make it work? I am working with VB NET

Comment: Do you know for sure that it is a .NET app that uses the `ErrorProvider` component? May I ask why you would want to do this in the first place? Are you trying to populate fields in a form and determine whether there are validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by 3rd party app. To see the tool tip the user would move the cursor over the red circle that appears next to the text box.

```
Private err As New ErrorProvider()
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        e.Cancel = True
        err.SetError(TextBox1, "This text box cannot be blank.")
    Else
        err.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```